# Resteasy resources not found in Jetty application

Tags: java, rest, jetty, resteasy

I am running an application with several components (JSP, resteasy, CDI, REST, Struts, maven) within an embedded jetty server (v.8) and am having an issue with my REST resources not being found. When the application starts I can see that the REST resources are being discovered and the one that the application fails to find when I hit the webpage is also there. What am I missing?
Thanks!

"[org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.ResteasyCdiExtension] Discovered CDI bean which is a JAX-RS resource com.mycompany.rs.SiteResource."

I have the following resteasy dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.Final</version>            
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependecy>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-cdi</artifactId> 
        <version>2.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have the following in my web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/api</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The Java rest resource has the following path annotation:

```
@Path("/site")
```

And the url I am accessing looks like:

```
http://localhost:9797/mycompany/api/site
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
2014-01-19 23:18:20,989 ERROR 755 [com.mycompany.rs.RestError] Unknown exception or error: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for relative : /site of full path: http://localhost:9797/mycompany/api/site?_=1390202300961
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized what the problem was - I am running this application through eclipse and resteasy was looking for the resource classes in src/webapp/WEB-INF/classes, but my build output folder was the eclipse default of target/classes.

Comment: Did you change the output folder or was it possible to reconfigure resteasy?